# org.xml.sax.SAXException while running web service client for SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap

I would like to know how would I remove the error in the following code.
My code for client is:

```
public class TestClient {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    try {
        String endpoint = "http://localhost:8080//services/HelloWorld";
        Service  service = new Service();
        Call     call    = (Call) service.createCall();

        call.setTargetEndpointAddress( new java.net.URL(endpoint) );
        call.setOperationName(new QName("http://example", "sayHelloWorldFrom"));
        call.addParameter("from", org.apache.axis.Constants.XSD_STRING, javax.xml.rpc.ParameterMode.IN);
        call.setReturnType(org.apache.axis.Constants.XSD_STRING);
        String ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] {"aaa"} );

        System.out.println("Sent 'Hello!', got '" + ret + "'");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The exception I receive when i run the code is:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle). log4j:WARN Please
>   initialize the log4j system properly. AxisFault  faultCode:
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException 
>   faultSubcode:   faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException:
>   SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected,
>   in something it was trying to deserialize.  faultActor:   faultNode:
>   faultDetail:      {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:MAQ
>
> org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child
>   element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to
>   deserialize.  at
>   org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1783)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2970)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
>     at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)    at
>   org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:796)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
>     at
>
> org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)     at
>   org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)   at
>   org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)     at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)  at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)    at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)    at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)    at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)    at
>   example.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:24)

When I try to send an `Object[] { }` without any parameters I do not get any error.

Here is the code for my webservice:

```
    @WebService
public class HelloWorld {
  @WebMethod
  public String sayHelloWorldFrom(String from) {
    String result = "Hello, world, from " + from;
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
  }
}
```